# viewDidAppear available for iOS 8.1 and later

Tags: ios

In the Quick Help Inspector (image attached) is written that function **viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)** is available for 8.1 and later. 
But in the Xcode documentation is written:

> Available in iOS 2.0 and later.

Can someone comment why it is like that?

[image: Quick Help Inspector]

Answer (score 1):

It is showing you help for swift function not objective c function.

*Swift came in iOS 8.1* obviously :)

This is objective C help -
[image]

Comment: Do you want to say that my app will crash on iOS 8?

Comment: Here is what is written about Swift: "In fact, you can target back to OS X Mavericks or iOS 7 with that same app." https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=2

Answer (score 0):

This screenshot tell you details about the function available in swift language that is introduce from iOS8.0

And in xcode documentation the detail you find is generic and with respect to ObjectiveC language the old1.

Both are correct difference lie in Language.